# How do I sum up the values in a column, conditional on whether the values of different columns match in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements

I have this data set which has values of confirmed coronavirus cases in each county on a particular day. I want to sum up the values of daily coronavirus cases in all counties of a particular state so I have a column for the number of cases by each state each day.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach with `dplyr` (version 1.0.0 or higher):

```
df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/live/us-counties.csv')

library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(date,state) %>%
  summarize(across(c(-fips,-county), sum))
# A tibble: 55 x 8
# Groups:   date [1]
   date       state                 cases deaths confirmed_cases confirmed_deaths probable_cases probable_deaths
   <fct>      <fct>                 <int>  <int>           <int>            <int>          <int>           <int>
 1 2020-06-11 Alabama               21989    744           21626              739             NA              NA
 2 2020-06-11 Alaska                  642      9             642               NA             NA              NA
 3 2020-06-11 Arizona               29981   1100              NA               NA             NA              NA
 4 2020-06-11 Arkansas              10368    165           10368              165             NA              NA
 5 2020-06-11 California           140123   4869          140123             4869             NA              NA
 6 2020-06-11 Colorado              28484   1573              NA               NA             NA              NA
 7 2020-06-11 Connecticut           44347   4120           42448             3283           1899             837
 8 2020-06-11 Delaware              10056    413              NA               NA             NA              NA
 9 2020-06-11 District of Columbia   9537    499            9537              499             NA              NA
10 2020-06-11 Florida               67363   2800           67363             2800             NA              NA
# … with 45 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `aggregate` in `base R`

```
aggregate(. ~ date + state, df[setdiff(names(df), 'county')], sum)
```

#### data

```
df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/live/us-counties.csv')
```